# Do continuation record the PC and register states?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, continuations

currently, when I am experimenting the continuation in functional languages, my understanding is that a continuation records the current program counter and register files, and when a continuation is returned, then the PC and the registered files will be restored to the values it has recorded.

So in the following dumb example from [Might's blog post](http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/),

```
; right-now : -> moment
(define (right-now)
  (call-with-current-continuation 
   (lambda (cc) 
     (cc cc))))

; go-when : moment -> ...
(define (go-when then)
  (then then))  


; An infinite loop:
(let ((the-beginning (right-now)))
  (display "Hello, world!")
  (newline)
  (go-when the-beginning))  ; here the-beginning continuation passed to go-when, which ultimately will have an continuation applied to an continuation, that returns a continuation, which will cause the the program point resumed to the PC and registers states recorded in it.
```

I am not sure my understanding right.. Please correct me if you think it is not.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Program counter and register files are not what the continuation records.

The best way to describe the meaning of call-with-current-continuation is that it records the program *context*. For instance, suppose you're evaluating the program

```
(+ 3 (f (call-with-current-continuation g)))
```

In this case, the *context* of the call-with-current-continuation expression would be

```
(+ 3 (f [hole]))
```

That is, the stuff surrounding the current expression.

Call-with-current-continuation captures one of these contexts. Invoking a continuation causes the replacement of the current context with the one stored in the continuation.

The idea of a context is a lot like that of a *stack*, except that there's nothing special about function calls in contexts.

This is a very brief treatment.  I strongly urge you to take a look at Shriram Krishnamurthi's (free, online) book [PLAI](http://www.plai.org/), in particular Part VII, for a more detailed and careful look at this topic.

Comment: Nice pointer! and I will surely explore that material later. 
btw, the main reason that I tend to think that way is that when the PC is resumed to the recorded one, then the flow of the program will be changed and continue from there to execute the rest computation

Comment: Great description of continuations.

Comment: I examined the call/cc, the way is executes: it captures the current continuation (cc), which contains current environments (locals or globals, or think as register files) and the place the cc is captured,then the cc is bound to a variable in a lambda terms, when the cc is invoked, the flow of the code will return to the place it was captured (think it to the PC recorded before), and returns what value that passes to the cc (if no value passed, the executing point will just return to the recorded PC, and execute from there). This is clearer with another infinite loop also in Might's blog.

Comment: The example I mentioned above:
`(let ((start #f))
  
  (if (not start)
      (call/cc (lambda (cc)
                 (set! start cc))))

  (display "Going to invoke (start)\n")
  
  (start))`